# SetCookie simply not working

Tags: php

I cannot get a cookie to set properly through WordPress theme. I am putting the following code on the bottom of my `functions.php` page for my theme.

```
function set_cookie() {
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $referrerID = $_GET['id'];
        setcookie('referrerid', $referrerID,time()+ 3600 * 24, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_cookie');
```

I even went as far as using JavaScript to alert if the script reached the function (which it did).

Why are my cookies not being set?? (The code works locally - outside of WordPress that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the HTTP headers are not sent already at the point you want to set the cookie. Here's how you can test that:

```
function set_cookie() {
  var_dump(headers_sent()); // should be bool(false)
  ...
```

Turning `WP_DEBUG` on in your config.php file may help also while debugging.

---

By the way, you really should be doing some filtering on `$_GET['id']`. This variable could contain anything. Casting it to a (positive) integer should go a long way:

```
$referrerID = absint($_GET['id']); // Note: absint() is a WP function
```

Comment: I can place that function anywhere and how will it let me know the results? Does it echo the information back?

Comment: Yes, [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) echoes its output.

Comment: it returned bool(false) - the cookie is still not being set though. Is there any way we could do a private chat if you have a free minute?

Comment: Not possible now. Could you inspect the HTTP response headers? Look for the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about retrieving such headers? I used this code just now but I don't think it's what you were looking for:

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}

Comment: You can use a tool like Firebug to inspect the HTTP request. An online tool like http://www.webpagetest.org/ could do the job as well.

Comment: Here are my test results - the cookie I'm setting is "referrerid" with the value of "1". It LOOKS good there, why is it not setting properly would you say based on these results?


http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120119_V7_2XVFT/1/details/cached/

Comment: Are you sure your browser is accepting cookies from your site's domain?

Comment: EDIT - Yeah, chrome is accepting cookies.

I know that I can use cookies (I used the same code outside of wordpress and it worked fine). How can i determine if they are accepting from a particular domain? I'll google that in the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use PHP's `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();`.

[You can find documentation on the two functions here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

The way I resolved my issues was to call the two functions before and after the opening and closing html tags like this:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <?php /* Wordpress loop and other tempate code here */ ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

The issue I was running into was calling a global function that used PHP's `setcookie();` and because WordPress processes the page progressively, the cookie couldn't be created due to  the page's headers already being sent.

PHP's output buffering function forces the headers to be sent before WordPress processes the page.

Hope this helps.